# Cannot find module "opn" after I updated 0.15.0

Tags: node.js, react-native

I updated  the version of react-native under dependencies to 0.15.0 and ran
`npm install`

And when I run 
`react-native upgrade`

I got a problem:

`Error: Cannot find module 'opn'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tianchishao/native/HotelCtrl/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/server/middleware/getDevToolsMiddleware.js:13:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at normalLoader (/Users/tianchishao/native/HotelCtrl/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/tianchishao/native/HotelCtrl/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)`

What's more, if I use 0.14.2, `react-native upgrade` works well.

How should I do to upgrade my project to 0.15.0?

Answer (score 0):

It's a cache error or something like that. A quick solution may be:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf ~/.npm
npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem updating from 0.13.0 to 0.14.2 ... Nothing worked, so I ended up running `react-native init` in a different folder and copying my source files, which worked.

Cheers!

Comment: Delete the folder `node_modules` and `npm install` again may work!